# Get contact records from list of custom object

Tags: apex, soql, query

I have a custom object with a lookupfield to contact:Contactpersoon__c. I make a query on this custom object with a filter so I end up with a list of the custom object with the related contacts. How do I get the list of contacts from this custom object list where Contactpersoon__c is the Id of contact.

I tried this as below but get the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   add(Relatie_Contact__c) from the type List

```
public with sharing class contactSelection {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list <contact> fetchContact() {
        Id org = [SELECT CurrentAccountIdComm__c FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1].CurrentAccountIdComm__c;
        List <Relatie_Contact__c> rc = [SELECT Contactpersoon__c FROM Relatie_Contact__c WHERE Actief__c = true AND Naam_organisatie__c = :org];
        list <contact> returnConList = new List <contact>(); 
        for(Relatie_Contact__c rel : rc ){
            returnConList.add(rel);    
        }
        return returnConList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you inserting records that you query from the database?

Comment: Yeah this code doesn't make any sense. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @sfdcfox im trying to find all the contacts which are in Relatie_Contact__c with the criteria WHERE Actief__c = true AND Naam_organisatie__c = :org and return these. the insert whas a typo edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general sense, if you just want the contact records, you can use a filter sub-query:

```
Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE 
  Id IN (SELECT Contactpersoon__c FROM Relatie_Contact__c WHERE
         Actief__c = true AND Naam_organisatie__c = :org)];
```

Comment: In this case isnt Id IN the Id of Relatie_Contact__c instead of Contactpersoon__c???

Comment: @Thomas No, `SomeObject[] parents = [SELECT ... FROM SomeObject WHERE Id IN (SELECT Field FROM OtherObject)]` is the same as `OtherObject[] records = [select field from otherobject]; Set<Id> values = new Set<Id>(); for(OtherObject record: records) { values.add(record.field); } SomeObject[] parents = [SELECT ... FROM SomeObject WHERE Id = :values]`, but without all of the extra code in the middle.

Comment: Please avoid redundant punctuation as it comes across quite rude.